# RecyclerView with Gridlayoutmanager extremely slow to load and respond

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I am building an app which shows a gridview of 2 columns, with the help of `recyclerview`. My code is as follows:

- **activity_main.xml**

  ```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycle"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```
- **custom_item_layout.xml**

  ```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--
       stroke with color and width for creating outer line
    -->
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#DBE2E9" />
  </shape>
  ```
- **row_layout.xml**

  ```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_item_layout"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <!--
    grid items for RecyclerView
    -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```
- **MainActivity.java**

  ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ArrayList for all app genres
    ArrayList appNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( "Augmented reality",
                   "Beauty", "Books & Reference",  "Comics", "Communication",
                   "Dating", "Entertainment", "Food & Drink",
                    "Games", "Kids", "Music & Audio", "Photography",
                    "Social", "Video Players & Editors"));
    ArrayList appImages = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(R.drawable.a_r, R.drawable.beauty, R.drawable.ic_books,
            R.drawable.ic_smashing_book_icon_comic_book_icon_11553392583tcjc, R.drawable.comms, R.drawable.date,
            R.drawable.entertainment, R.drawable.foods, R.drawable.games,
            R.drawable.kids, R.drawable.music, R.drawable.camera,
            R.drawable.social, R.drawable.video));
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // get the reference of RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        // set a GridLayoutManager with default vertical orientation and 2 number of columns
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
        //  call the constructor of CustomAdapter to send the reference and data to Adapter
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, appNames,appImages);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter); // set the Adapter to RecyclerView
    }
  }
  ```
- **CustomAdapter.java**

  ```
   public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    ArrayList appNames;
    ArrayList appImages;
    Context context;
    boolean allowed = false;
    LottieAlertDialog.Builder alert;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList appNames, ArrayList appImages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.appNames = appNames;
        this.appImages = appImages;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // infalte the item Layout
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyViewHolder mholder=(MyViewHolder) holder;
        mholder.image.setImageResource((Integer) appImages.get(position));  
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return appNames.size();
    }
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
  }
  ```

**All my vector assets are of size:**

```
android:width="512dp"
android:height="512dp"
android:viewportWidth="512"
android:viewportHeight="512">
```

The problem is that , when I run the app it takes so long to load, and the device keeps on freezing. I have no clue as to why this is happening. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use image processing libraries like Glide to load images into imageview . That might help

Answer (score 0):

Following @Faisal recommendation, here I show the steps:

1.) Add the following dependencies intro build.gradle module:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
// Glide v4 uses this new annotation processor -- see https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

2.) To load the picture:

```
    Glide.with(yourimageview.getContext())
            .load(Your string path or uri to the photo)
            .into(yourimageview);
```

Too me it worked! Now it's really fast